# OAuth2 for managing Amazon Alexa Lists

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I want to create a button in my website that takes the user to an Amazon URL that allows the user to grant my website permission to manage their Alexa lists (and then generates a code that it includes in a GET request that happens as a redirect to a "callback" URL that I registered as the redirect_uri when setting up OAuth2 in Amazon).

But I've found [Amazon's docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html) incredibly unhelpful.

I see permissions / scopes mentioned [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html#missing_permissions) called `alexa::household:lists:read alexa::household:lists:write`.

But I don't even know whether those scopes are valid for what I'm trying to do. [Christina thinks not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76025645/470749).

I've set up my API endpoint (which I'll specify at `redirectUrl`) to [exchange the Amazon authorization code for an Amazon access token](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html#step-5) following the code examples shown there.

I've set oauth2BaseUrl to be 'https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa' (found at https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/authorization-code-grant.html).

I created an Alexa "skill" on the AWS site (even though I don't know if I'm supposed to).

For client ID, I'm using the one for my Alexa skill that I created. Is that correct?

Here are permissions I've added in my Skill:

[image]

I always get:

```
400 Bad Request
An unknown scope was requested
```

But if I just use these different scopes instead, I see it behave how I'd expect (but I lack List permissions): `alexa::skills:account_linking postal_code profile:user_id`.

P.S. Since I'm not looking to offer a federated login feature, I'm not interested in setting up Login With Amazon unless it's required for what I'm trying to do (just manage someone's Alexa lists).

Comment: I tried asking a more complicated version of this question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75967998/470749 but did not learn a solution so am asking a simpler version here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get my Next.js app to connect to my Amazon Alexa lists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77366772/470749